# ICACLS options: Why is /t needed with (OI)(OC)?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

If I use ICACLS.exe to set permissions on a folder with a command such as

```
icacls "C:\Some\Directory" /grant "somedomain\someUser:(OI)(CI)F" /t
```

why is the /t option necessary?  Is it not the case that (OI)(CI) will cause the permissions to be inherited to all objects within the `C:\Some\Directory` tree?

To be a bit more specific, suppose in my example above I have a directory `C:\Some\Directory\Tree`.  Suppose that this directory has *no* explicit permissions defined.  Adding the explicit permission  "somedomain\someUser:(OI)(CI)F" to that directory would accomplish nothing, since it is already inherited.  Does icacls even do this? (Edit: yes, if you wait long enough!)  So if I know a directory tree has no explicit permissions, I really don't need the /t option (which wastes a tremendous amount of time on an 8TB directory tree with hundreds of millions of files...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some experimenting on a trivial directory tree shows that:

1) The (OI)(CI) does indeed cause the permissions to be inherited - as inherited ACE's in the DACL of course, not explicit ACE's - to all sub-objects (given that inheritance has not been disabled on the sub-object), as one would expect.

2) The /t option causes icacls to traverse the tree and add the exact same permission to each *sub-directory* as an *explicit* permission.

The result is that if one looks at the security permissions on a sub-directory, you will see *two identical* entries, one being the inherited permission, and one being the directory explicit permission setting (unless inheritance was disabled on the subdirectory or some other intervening directory).

Whether one wants this or not is another question, but likely not.  Having the permission specified twice is not particularly useful, unless there is some future changes you need to guard against.

On a massive file system, this can take a loooooooong time to complete.

The fact that the documentation states "whether or not they are set to inherit permissions" perhaps is to alert you to:

1) copying as explicit permissions to all sub directories may not be necessary if the permission contains `(OI)(CI)`

but

2) if a subdirectory is set to not inherit permissions, this actually accomplishes something significant: on such a directory, the permission would not be inherited from the parent (i.e. the `(OI)(CI)` inheritance is suppressed), but it would still be there by virtue of being added as an explicit permission.

Comment: Your little research project helped me immensely. I've seen the `icacls /t` option thrown around pretty carelessly (especially by some LLMs I know). The ramifications of recursively applying explicit permissions could be quite huge. If a directory doesn't inherit, there may be a reason for it. Recursively applying explicit inheritance permissions could leave quite the mess to clean up...

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it not the case that (OI)(CI) will cause the permissions to be inherited?

No. This is explained by the description for `/t`:

> Traverse all subfolders to match files/directories. This will apply permission changes to all subfolders **whether or not they are set to inherit permissions from the parent**.

Source [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  It says: if inheritance is not set, it will copy the permissions to all sub folders (which clearly accomplishes something significant); and if inheritance is set, it will also copy the permissions, but it does not say why this is necessary!  If inheritance means, well, means inheritance, then I don't see why it is necessary.  The mere fact that they state "whether or not they are set to inherit permissions" says that there is indeed a question here to be answered.

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh There are different kinds of inheritance. `(OI)(CI)/t` will set the inheritance to `(OI)(CI)` if it is not set at all, set to `(IO)` or some other combination than `(OI)(CI)`

Comment: David - Don't you have 1,000,000 rep on SU yet already? Before you know it, you will be higher than Harry "The Mac Daddy" MC!!

Comment: @DavidPostill : your second comment still doesn't set me straight - there must be something fundamental that I don't understand?  I edited my question to be a bit more specific.  Perhaps you can have another look?  Thanks.